# What happens if you don't specify the directoryindex in your apache configure file?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services

Just curious, if I didn't specify a DirectoryIndex anywhere in my amazon web services apache configure file, but there is a file called index.html in my DocumentRoot, when a user requests index.html what would happen? Would it just default to a 500 error?

Thanks.

Comment: I think this setting is for the case when the user *does not* request `/path/to/index.html` directly, but rather something like `/path/to/` (a "directory").

Comment: Right now I'm trying to test and I think it goes back to my index.html page anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DirectoryIndex` has a default of `index.html`, so if you did not specify anything, it would use that.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html

The directory index file is served when a "directory" URL is requested, such as `https://my.site.com/`.  If someone requested the index file directly (say, `https://my.site.com/path/index.xhtml`), that would be served regardless of setting (or result in a 404 if missing).